# How to get around using a wildcard in Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I tried using a wild card and after searching the web it seemed like it wasn't possible.

I am trying to look in cell b2 and if the letter "a" appears anywhere in it AND either C2 or D2 are filled with anything then b2 will turn red.

This is the formula i was trying to use  and it obviously does not work.

```
 =AND(B2="*a*",OR(C2<>"",D2<>""))
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Find() Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628):

```
 =AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("a",b2)),OR(C2<>"",D2<>""))
```

That is Case specific.

If you want it not to be case specific then use the [SEARCH() Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495).

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",b2)),OR(C2<>"",D2<>""))
```